# Accessing problem when transmitting data from Angular to Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cors, xmlhttprequest

I am working in a project with Angular 13 in frontend and Spring Boot 3.6 in Backend. When I try to send data from frontend to backend, I have this error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/authentification' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.